# c# to read xml file and update the checkboxes with the nodes

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq

I have an xml file like this:

```
<servers>
<general name="1">      
        <service name="ser1"/>
        <service name="ser2"/>  
</general>
<general name="2">      
        <service name="ser1"/>
        <service name="ser2"/>  
</general>
</servers>
```

In my winform application, I have a treeview list with checkbox property set to true.What I am trying to achieve is that I am attempting to read this xml file and update both the parent and child node to this tree view.

What I have tried is:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\\path.xml");
        TreeNode node;            
            var gnrl = from general in doc.Descendants("general")
                       select new
                       {
                           parent = general.Attribute("name").Value,
                           child = general.Descendants("service")
                       };
            //Loop through results
            foreach (var general in gnrl)
            {
                 // Add a root node.
            node = dcselectview.Nodes.Add(String.Format(general.parent));
                foreach (var ser in general.child)
                {
                        // Add a node as a child of the previously added node.
                        node = node.Nodes.Add(String.Format(ser.Attribute("name").Value));                        
                }
           }
```

it reads the file and all details are updated but not in a proper way. rather it is shown as below:

[image]

**Needed:**

I want the parent element to be on top and down-right to it,the child elements. If possible, it would be nice if I dont have checkboxes for parent elements.

Any help would be really appreciated..

**EDIT:**

My code edited. Now I am getting as shown in new picture below:

[image]

I want the 2 black lines to be in same line,not as child node of another..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help::But I have found another solution of my own::

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"path\\test.xml");            

        // Add nodes to treeView1.
        TreeNode pnode;
        TreeNode cnode;
            var gnrl = from general in doc.Descendants("general")
                       select new
                       {
                           parent = general.Attribute("name").Value,
                           child = general.Descendants("service")
                       };
            //Loop through results
            foreach (var general in gnrl)
            {
                 // Add a root node.
            pnode = treeview.Nodes.Add(String.Format(general.parent));
                foreach (var ser in general.child)
                {
                // Add a node as a child of the previously added node.
                cnode = pnode.Nodes.Add(String.Format(ser.Attribute("name").Value));                        
                }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a hierarchical structure, like this?

[image]

If so, I recommend you to look at the Treeview:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.checkboxes.aspx

Comment: see  my edited question and new picture...how can that be sorted out..??

Answer (score 0):

You have to add parent as a node first

```
public static bool LoadNodesFromXML()
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\\path.xml");
        var root = doc.Root;
        var childenode = dcselectview.Nodes.Add(root.Attribute("Name").Value);
        foreach (var xElement in root .Elements())
                {
                    InsertNode(childenode, xElement);
                }
}


private void InsertNode(TreeNode parent, XElement element)
        {
            var childenode = parent.Nodes.Add(element.Attribute("Name").Value);
            if(element.Elements().Count() > 0)
                foreach (var xElement in element.Elements())
                {
                    InsertNode(childenode, xElement);
                }

        }
```

Comment: see  my edited question and new picture...how can that be sorted out..??

Comment: you have to write a method and recursively call that method to add child nodes, let me edit my answer

Comment: Edited answer, calling insertNode method recursively

Answer (score 0):

Try this you will get

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\\test.xml");

        IEnumerable<XElement> Xele = doc.XPathSelectElements("//general");

        foreach (XElement xe in Xele.Descendants())
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(xe.Attribute("name").Value);
        dcselectview.Parent.Text =xe.Parent.Attribute("name").Value; // here parent  value ---->  name="1" and name="2" 
        dcselectview.Nodes.Add(xe.Attribute("name").Value); // ser1     ser2        ser1        ser2
        }
```

Comment: see  my edited question and new picture...how can that be sorted out..??

Comment: you have to add it in same level then go through treelist in C#

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static class TreeViewExtension
{
    public static bool LoadNodesFromXML(this TreeView tv, string xml)
    {
        try
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode();
            rootNode.Text = doc.Root.ToString().Split('>')[0] + ">";
            rootNode.LoadTreeNodes(doc.Root.Elements());
            tv.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
            return true;
        }
        catch { return false; }
    }
    public static void LoadTreeNodes(this TreeNode parentNode, IEnumerable<XElement> elements)
    {
        foreach (var e in elements) {
            TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode();                
            childNode.Text = e.ToString().Split('>')[0] + ">";
            parentNode.Nodes.Add(childNode);
            childNode.LoadTreeNodes(e.Elements());
        }
    }
}
//Usage:
var yourInputXMLString = "<servers><general name=\"1\"><service name=\"ser1\"/>" +
                         "<service name=\"ser2\"/></general><general name=\"2\">" +
                         "<service name=\"ser1\"/><service name=\"ser2\"/>" +
                         "</general></servers>";
treeView1.LoadNodesFromXML(yourInputXMLString);
```

[image]

Comment: see  my edited question and new picture...how can that be sorted out..??

Comment: @vysakh do you want to show the tags or just the name attributes? I mean instead of `<service ...>` just `ser1, ser2`? Your output **doesn't** show any important info, just the tree structure because you bolded all the node text.